# Beautifulsoup content returning list index out of range

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm following these tutorials http://importpython.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-get-beautifulsoup-to-filter.html and http://importpython.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-screen-scrape-craigslist-using.html and even with copy pasted code I can't seem to get the title of the link to print because I get a list index out of range on lines 11 and 8 respectively. What am I doing wrong if I am copyposting the code. I've tried other variations such as returning just the links and that works completely fine, so I don't think it's a local issue

**EDIT**

The problem is the following code (from http://importpython.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-screen-scrape-craigslist-using.html):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup   #1
from urllib2 import urlopen               #2

site = "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/rea/" #3
html = urlopen(site)                      #4
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)                #5
postings = soup('p')                      #6

for post in postings:                     #7
    print post('a')[0].contents[0]        #8
    print post('a')[0]['href']            #9
```

gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) of code that demonstrates the issue in your actual question, not just off-site links.

Answer (score 0):

This is relying on Craigslist's html structure, which has changed. You will get your 'correct' result in the second 'a' tag:

```
print post('a')[1].contents[0]
print post('a')[1]['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is pretty powerful... so don't be lazy and use all its power:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
postings = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'row'})

for post in postings:
   info_container = post.find('span', {'class':'pl'}).find('a')
   print info_container.text
   print info_container['href']
```

I always try to avoid to hardcode arrays sizing in my code. 
And use the find function, it's most intuitive